# Iterating over a list and defining the range accordingly

Tags: list-manipulation, iteration

I have the following list,

```
l = {{"a", "b"}, {"a", "b"}, {"c", "d"}, {"e", "f"}, {"e", "f"},
     {"x", "y", "z"}, {"m", "n", "o"}, {"p", "q", "s"}};
```

for each sublist I want to count them and make a polynomial out of it, for example for `{"a", "b"}` I have

```
Total[x^-2 x^Map[Length, Select[l, ContainsAll[{"a", "b"}]]]]
```

Note that the `x^-2` terms is important to be there for my later calculations. Now if I want to do this for `{"x","y","z"}` I shall do

```
Total[x^-3 x^Map[Length, Select[l, ContainsAll[{"x", "y","z"}]]]]
```

So as you see the power of first term is now `x^-3`, now if I want to do this on a table I can write,

```
AssociationThread[
 l -> Table[
   Total[x^-i x^Map[Length, Select[l, ContainsAll[l[[i]]]]]], {i, 
    Length[l]}]]
```

My question is how to iterate the `x^-i` such that it works correspondingly? meaning for entries of length 2 the power should be `x^-2`, for entries of length 3 the power should be `x^-3` and generalisable to higher length in similar manner.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, `x^-Length@l[[i]]` should work, no? Also, a more concise alternative: `AssociationMap[
 Total[x^-Length@# x^Map[Length, Select[l, ContainsAll@#]]] &, l]`

Comment: Thank you that is indeed sorted it :)