# Optimising Table iteration

Tags: performance-tuning, list-manipulation

I've asked a question [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/205041/iterating-over-a-list-and-defining-the-range-accordingly) which was resolved by tweaking my code a little. So I shall reiterate, for the following list,

```
l = {{"a", "b"}, {"a", "b"}, {"c", "d"}, {"e", "f"}, {"e", "f"},
     {"x", "y", "z"}, {"m", "n", "o"}, {"p", "q", "s"}};
```

I want to count each sublist and make a polynomial from them, I do this by:

```
AssociationThread[
 l -> Table[
   Total[(x^-Length@l[[i]]) x^
      Map[Length, Select[l, ContainsAll[l[[i]]]]]], {i, Length[l]}]]
```

This code does the job correctly yet, the original list I am working with has 38968 sublists and thus the code would take a lot of time to be complied - I wonder how does one optimise this?

I used `ParallelTable` but for some reason it takes more time!

```
In[130]:= 
AssociationThread[
  l -> Table[
    Total[(x^-Length@l[[i]]) x^
       Map[Length, Select[l, ContainsAll[l[[i]]]]]], {i, 
     Length[l]}]] // AbsoluteTiming
AssociationThread[
  l -> ParallelTable[
    Total[(x^-Length@l[[i]]) x^
       Map[Length, Select[l, ContainsAll[l[[i]]]]]], {i, 
     Length[l]}]] // AbsoluteTiming

Out[130]= {0.000812, <|{"a", "b"} -> 2, {"c", "d"} -> 1, {"e", "f"} ->
    2, {"x", "y", "z"} -> 1, {"m", "n", "o"} -> 1, {"p", "q", "s"} -> 
   1|>}

Out[131]= {0.002713, <|{"a", "b"} -> 2, {"c", "d"} -> 1, {"e", "f"} ->
    2, {"x", "y", "z"} -> 1, {"m", "n", "o"} -> 1, {"p", "q", "s"} -> 
   1|>}
```

Comment: I'm confused. Isn't your desired output identical to the output of `Counts[l]`? What am I missing?

Comment: @MarcoB I got mislead as well: try this list: l = {{"a", "a", "b"}, {"a", "b"}, {"a", "a"}, {"b", "b"}, {"b", 
    "b"}, {"c", "d"}, {"e", "f"}, {"e", "f"}, {"x", "y", "z"}, {"m", 
    "n", "o"}, {"p", "q", "s"}}; and you'll see that the output is different. Maybe it's worth editing the OP with this example as well to clarify the difference, but I'm not 100% sure

Comment: @marcoB in this very specific case the output is like that because powers of x are cancelling each other - this is not a general rule for the list that I am working with so the output is indeed correct as you see and one must use the formula I used...

Comment: I suggest you to update the test list with something more clear, as the one I provide in my answer below :)

Answer (score 2):

Here is an approach that is around 10 times faster (see below for timing of old approach on my machine):

```
al = AssociationThread[# -> 1] & /@ l;
AssociationThread[
  Keys /@ al -> Table[
    Total[
     (x^-Length@al[[i]]) 
      x^Map[
        Length,
        Pick[al, Times @@@ Lookup[al, Keys@al[[i]], 0], 1]
        ]
     ],
    {i, Length[al]}
    ]
  ] // RepeatedTiming
(* {0.00012, <|{"a", "b"} -> 2, {"c", "d"} -> 1, {"e", "f"} -> 
   2, {"x", "y", "z"} -> 1, {"m", "n", "o"} -> 1, {"p", "q", "s"} -> 
   1|>} *)
```

This works by (ab)using [`Association`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Association.html)s as hash-maps for faster membership checks. We first convert the list `l` into a list of associations (`al`) where the keys are the elements from the sublists of `l` and the values are all `1`. Using `Lookup`, we perform a lookup in all of `al` at once, with non-existing keys defaulting to `0`. We then [`Pick`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Pick.html) the sublists where the product of all lookup results is `1`.

#### Timing of old approach

Compared to the one in the question:

```
AssociationThread[
  l -> Table[
    Total[
     (x^-Length@l[[i]]) 
      x^Map[
        Length,
        Select[l, ContainsAll[l[[i]]]]
        ]
     ],
    {i, Length[l]}
    ]
  ] // RepeatedTiming
(* {0.0009, <|{"a", "b"} -> 2, {"c", "d"} -> 1, {"e", "f"} -> 
   2, {"x", "y", "z"} -> 1, {"m", "n", "o"} -> 1, {"p", "q", "s"} -> 
   1|>} *)
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's first create a test list:

```
l = Join @@ 
   ConstantArray[{{"a", "a", "b"}, {"a", "b"}, {"a", "b"}, {"a", 
      "a"}, {"b", "b"}, {"b", "b"}, {"c", "d"}, {"e", "f"}, {"e", 
      "f"}, {"x", "y", "z"}, {"m", "n", "o"}, {"p", "q", "s"}}, 20];
```

One can use the following code to speed up the calculation:

```
RepeatedTiming[
 dl = DeleteDuplicates[l];
 exp1 = Length /@ dl;
 exp2 = Length /@ Select[l, ContainsAll[#]] & /@ dl;
 m3 = AssociationThread[dl -> Total /@ ((x^-exp1) (x^exp2))]]
```

> {0.023, <|{"a", "a", "b"} -> 20 + 40/x, {"a", "b"} -> 
>      40 + 20 x, {"a", "a"} -> 60 + 20 x, {"b", "b"} -> 
>      80 + 20 x, {"c", "d"} -> 20, {"e", "f"} -> 40, {"x", "y", "z"} -> 
>      20, {"m", "n", "o"} -> 20, {"p", "q", "s"} -> 20|>}

Compared with the old method:

```
RepeatedTiming[m1 = AssociationThread[l -> Table[
     Total[
      (x^-Length@l[[i]])
        x^Map[Length, Select[l, ContainsAll[l[[i]]]]]
      ], {i, Length[l]}]
   ]]
```

> {0.624, <|{"a", "a", "b"} -> 20 + 40/x, {"a", "b"} -> 
>      40 + 20 x, {"a", "a"} -> 60 + 20 x, {"b", "b"} -> 
>      80 + 20 x, {"c", "d"} -> 20, {"e", "f"} -> 40, {"x", "y", "z"} -> 
>      20, {"m", "n", "o"} -> 20, {"p", "q", "s"} -> 20|>}

```
m1==m3
```

> True

and ~ 30 times faster.

Comment: Thank you but could you please read the comment I've posted under my question - it will answer your question. As it stands the output of yours is wrong as it is no matching with mine.

Comment: Are you sure? can you provide an example list where the output doesn't match yours? It seems to me that the two codes do the same thing :) If you notice, I changed the list so that the powers of X don't simplify, and the output of your code is the same as mine!